# How to convert a string of a decimal number from any base to a decimal number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to write a function that can convert a string with a given base to a decimal number.

Let's say the function is `convert` calling `convert` should give me the following output

```
convert('3.14', base=10) ~= 3.14
convert('100.101', base=2) == 4.625
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding site. If you are looking to write a function, please show some evidence of that. Right now it looks like you're looking to have a function written.

Comment: All your questions lack the part: what you tried so far ? None want to spend time to write code for you without seen you put effort in at least try something: write/type a variable name, name a function, define the function at least ...

Answer (score 1):

To convert floating-point numbers from one base to another, you can just break the number in half, handle the whole and the part separately, and then join them back together.

```
num = '100.101'
base = 2

# split into whole and part
whole = num[:num.index('.')]
part = num[num.index('.') + 1:]

# get the logarithmic size of the part so we can treat it as a fraction
# e.g. '101/1000'
denom = base ** len(part)

# use python's built-in base conversion to convert the whole numbers
# thanks @EthanBrews for mentioning this
b10_whole = int(whole, base=base)
b10_part = int(part, base=base)

# recombine the integers into a float to return
b10_num = b10_whole + (b10_part / denom)
return b10_num
```

Thanks to the other answerer @EthanBrews for mentioning that integer stuff was already built-in. Unfortunately the same construction doesn't same to exist for `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports already. Simply use `my_int = int(str, base)`

Comment: Are you sure about that? The question includes both fractions and integers, the above works only for integers. E.g. consider this: `int("0.1", 2)`